# Missing data when reading data over telnet in Perl

Tags: perl, telnet

I am trying to read and write data to multiple device(more than 30) over network as part of a test. I have a Perl script which does all the read and write over telnet for a single device. I am taking that Perl script and running multiple duplicate instances of it.
Now the problem is I am seeing that some data is missing when reading  from the devices and this is causing the test to be marked as failed. Also when writing data I sometime see that the data is not sent. Both of this occurs completely at random and about 30 to 100 times for every say 2000 iterations of the test, per device.

What might be causing the problem? Is it related to telnet, or would it be a network issue (company wide network?), or is it some other problem?

EDIT:

I am using the [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aTelnet) module.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you flushing your data when sending the data over the sockets?
Are you using autoflush?
I would then use Wireshark to look at the network to check if the data is missing when sending or not

Comment: I was assuming all the output data in telnet are flushed automatically. From the link http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.03/lib/Net/Telnet.pm in "What to Know before Using" section. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You did not mention before the used perl module. I would then use Wireshark to look at the network to check if the data is missing when sending or not.

Comment: Added the module. I will try using Wireshark.

Comment: using Wireshark helped. I have added it to your answer. You might have to approve it or edit it yourself. Thanks...